# Kubernetes unable to pull images from gcr.io

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to setup Kubernetes for the first time. I am following the Fedora Manual installation guide: http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config.html

I am trying to get the kubernetes addons running , specifically the kube-ui. I created the service and replication controller like so:

```
kubectl create -f cluster/addons/kube-ui/kube-ui-rc.yaml --namespace=kube-system
kubectl create -f cluster/addons/kube-ui/kube-ui-svc.yaml --namespace=kube-system
```

When i run

```
kubectl get events --namespace=kube-system
```

I see errors such as this:

```
 Failed to pull image "gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0": image pull failed for gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0, this may be because there are no credentials on this request.  details: (Authentication is required.)
```

How am i supposed to tell kubernetes to authenticate? This isnt covered in the documentation. So how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened due to a recent outage to gce storage as a result of which all of us went through this error while pulling images from gcr (which uses gce storage on the backend).

Are you still seeing this error ?

Answer (score 0):

as the message says, you need credentials. Are you using Google Container Engine? Then you need to run

```
gcloud config set project <your-project>
gcloud config set compute/zone <your-zone, like us-central1-f>
gcloud beta container clusters get-credentials --cluster <your-cluster-name>
```

then your GCE cluster will have the credentials